# THERE ARE ONLY FOUR OF THESE! (Not shouting, just trying to tell you something)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**The first two images corresponding to the actor to the left are complete, the last two aren't. Also, all the four images share something in common - something that's missing... Replace the question marks and explain why that's correct.**

---

[image]

---

*Note: Don't waste your time looking for movies, tv shows or similar related to the actors. You won't find anything relevant. Find their names and then... the rest is up to you.*

Comment: To save everyone a step, the actors are rot13(Zbetna Serrzna, Puevfgbcure Trbetr, Ora Xvatfyrl, Wrss Oevqtrf)

Comment: "The first two images corresponding to the actor to the left are complete" sounds unclear.  Perhaps "The first two images _consisting of an actor on the left and a graphic on the right_ are complete."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the first question mark is going to be

> a group of three lozenges arranged in a roughly heart-shaped formation:
>  [image]

and the second one will be

> the head of a trident.
>  [image]

In case these still don't seem all that obvious, the actors are (Thanks, @ed-murphy)

> Morgan Freeman, Christopher George, Ben Kingsley, and Jeff Bridges

which, at least if you are a little bit weird, will immediately bring to mind

> towns.

In particular, these ones:

> Freetown, the capital of [Sierra Leone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_Leone),
>  Georgetown, the capital of [Guyana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guyana),
>  Kingstown, the capital of [Saint Vincent and the Grenadines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Vincent_and_the_Grenadines), and
>  Bridgetown, the capital of [Barbados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbados).
>
>  <sup>(As @Stiv helpfully points out in the comments, the hint in the title is typed in "all capitals", suggesting we're most likely on the right track. The count in the hint also agrees, at least if we ignore the (super hero themed?) [legislative capital of South Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Town).)</sup>

The respective patterns then are the

> borders between the colours in the flags of these countries.

Like so:

> [image]

Comment: Well spotted +1 I have a feeling the title may be being delivered in the style of a rot13(GBJA pevre) too, though that may just be my imagination :)

Comment: Well done! This is it. The title rot13(n ybg bs bs *pncvgny* yrggref gurer.)

Comment: @Stiv I may not have actually read what the rot13 in  your comment says before writing that part of the answer, but now that I have, I really like your take on it. Hope you don't mind the answer misrepresenting the facts, as the truth is still available here :-)

Comment: @Bass Ha, you know the intended meaning didn't actually strike me at all! But I shall happily play a part in this theatre of mystery...